# A non-rotating log4j file appender?

Tags: java, log4j

We're using Java 6 and the latest version of log4j.  We have a system process that rotates logs and so we don't need to use what we currently have ...

```
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A1.File=/opt/tomcat-instance/nnadbmon/logs/log4j.log
log4j.appender.A1.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
```

What is an appender we can use that will not rotate logs but can continue to utilize the date pattern and file we have included?  Thanks, - Dave

Comment: I don't understand - "rolling" refers to logging to "log4j.log.2011-07-29" instead of "log4j.log.2011-07-28" when the day changes. If you want to "continue to utilize the date pattern" what do you actually want to change?

Comment: So you want the data suffix on the filename, but not rolling files?  Isn't that going to be hugely confusing?

Comment: Actually, when the day changes, I thought it would roll over log4j.log to log4j.log.2011-07-28 and continue logging to log4j.log. I think the OP just wants a date suffix to the log4j.log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the common ones:

Common Appenders

- FileAppender, it appends log events to a file.
- RollingFileAppender, it extends FileAppender to backup the log files
  when they reach a certain size.
- DailyRollingFileAppender it extends FileAppender so that the
  underlying file is rolled over at a user chosen frequency.
- ConsoleAppender - it appends log events to System.out or System.err
  using a layout specified by the user. The default target is
  System.out.

Referenced from here [link](http://www.allapplabs.com/log4j/log4j_appenders.htm)

I would recommend using the RollingFileAppender and have your system log roller do the daily rotation.

If you want the date on the file as well you may need to write your own FileAppender.